# Alert via jQuery não funcionando conforme planejado

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wcf

Preciso de um help!

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto web, e nele eu chamo por jQuery um WCF SOAP de teste, bem simples, em um botão, e retorna um alert com um valor. Está funcionando, porém não do jeito que eu quero. No primeiro clique não aparece nada, no segundo aparece 2 alerts, no terceiro 3, e assim por diante. Alguém poderia verificar e me ajudar por favor?

Chamada do serviço:

```
teste() {
  jQuery.support.cors = true;
  const jhRequest = "<s:Envelope xmlns:a=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\" xmlns:s=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">" +
    "<s:Header>" +
    "<a:Action s:mustUnderstand=\"1\">http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData</a:Action>" +
    "<a:MessageID>urn:uuid:7fdde7b6-64c8-4402-9af1-cc848f15888f</a:MessageID>" +
    "<a:ReplyTo>" +
    "<a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>" +
    "</a:ReplyTo>" +
    "<a:To s:mustUnderstand=\"1\">http://localhost:61548/Service1.svc/jh/</a:To>" +
    "</s:Header>" +
    "<s:Body>" +
    "<GetData xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">" +
    "<value>9</value>" +
    "</GetData>" +
    "</s:Body>" +
    "</s:Envelope>";

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnWCFWSHttp").click(function () {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:61548/Service1.svc/jh/",
        data: jhRequest,
        timeout: 10000,
        contentType: "application/soap+xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        async: true,
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
          $(data).find("GetDataResponse").each(function () {
            alert($(this).find("GetDataResult").text());
          });
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
          alert(error);

        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Vc está procurando com `.find` dentro do retorno do Ajax algo com esse nome `GetDataResponse`... se não tiver, não irá dar nenhum alert, mas se tiver, irá dar alerts de acordo com a quantidade que achar.

Comment: Ele procura no envelope SOAP que coloquei na variável jhRequest. No caso ele sempre vai aumentando um alert a cada clique, saberia me informar fiz algo errado ou se tem outra alternativa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O aumento na quantidade de chamadas de `alert` acontece porque você está vinculado um novo evento a cada clique no elemento `#btnWCFWSHttp`.

Minha sugestão seria remover os eventos vinculados ao elemento antes de adicionar um novo, utilizando o `.off()`. Por exemplo:

```
$("#btnWCFWSHttp").off().click(function () {
    //your code
}
```